# The calling thread cannot access this object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, accessibility

this code "var results.." throwing exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". LINQ query is not bad.

Please what I am doing wrong?

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    bool doStg()
    {
        try 
        {
            var results = from t in db.table
                          select t;

            //doing some things..

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Exception.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool stepByStep() 
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => info.Text = "Step 1"), null);
        if (!doStg()) { return false; }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = 33), null);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => info.Text = "Step 2"), null);
        if (!doStg()) { return false; }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = 66), null);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => info.Text = "Step 3"), null);
        if (!doStg()) { return false; }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = 100), null);

        return true;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            args.Result = stepByStep(); 
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            object result = args.Result;
            if ((bool)result) { MessageBox.Show("Done"); }
            else { MessageBox.Show("Processing stopped."); }
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Exception Source: "System.Data.Linq"

TargetSite: {System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlNode VisitInvocation(System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression)}

Comment: Why have you commented out the majority of `doStg`?

Comment: @Chaos: Because it's not relevant.

Comment: What is the full exception?  Also, the bits you commented out, which actually iterate over the linq query, what does that look like?

Comment: @Robert - Clearly the exception is not related to the LINQ query so there must be something else in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Move the following line of code:

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
```

into your `stepByStep()` method body, and then pass `db` as a parameter to your `doStg()` method.

```
    bool doStg(DataClassesDataContext db)
    {
        try 
        {
            var results = from t in db.table
                          select t;

            //doing some things..

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Exception.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool stepByStep() 
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(); 

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => info.Text = "Step 1"), null);
        if (!doStg(db)) { return false; }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = 33), null);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => info.Text = "Step 2"), null);
        if (!doStg(db)) { return false; }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = 66), null);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => info.Text = "Step 3"), null);
        if (!doStg(db)) { return false; }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = 100), null);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: My WPF is a bit weak. Are you saying that non-ui elements are protected from cross-thread manipulation?

Comment: @Chaos: The problem is that, in the original code, the `DataContext` is running on a separate thread. It's the `BackgroundWorker` that's causing this, not WPF. I'm not sure what the underlying mechanism is, but I am almost positive that putting the `DataContext` on the same thread as the Linq query will solve the problem.

Comment: @Chaos: If your DataClassesDataContext inherits from DispatcherObject (if it is a DependencyObject for instance), it will have thread affinity.  Since we don't know what this class looks like, this is a good assumption.

Comment: @Abe: `DataClassesDataContext` is most likely either a Linq to SQL data context, or an Entity Framework data context.  I don't know how the thread affinity works on those objects, but it's the only thing running outside of the `BackgroundWorker` thread.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: it's absolutely same. It thows the same exception on same row :(

Comment: SOLVED, in linq query I have WHERE something == combo.selectedvalue. Problem is that It cant get the selected value from UI. I put there on combo selection changed set value in variable :)